# NegativeArraySizeException in hopscotch implementation within neo4j

Tags: neo4j

## Neo4j community version 3.3.1

In current situation number of nodes is high with high churn (ie addition/deletion of nodes/relationships)

Exception stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.IntArrayBasedKeyTable.initializeTable(IntArrayBasedKeyTable.java:54)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.IntArrayBasedKeyTable.<init>(IntArrayBasedKeyTable.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.LongKeyTable.<init>(LongKeyTable.java:27)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.LongKeyTable.newInstance(LongKeyTable.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.LongKeyTable.newInstance(LongKeyTable.java:22)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.PowerOfTwoQuantizedTable.grow(PowerOfTwoQuantizedTable.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.HopScotchHashingAlgorithm.growTable(HopScotchHashingAlgorithm.java:290)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.HopScotchHashingAlgorithm.put(HopScotchHashingAlgorithm.java:188)
    at org.neo4j.collection.primitive.hopscotch.PrimitiveLongHashSet.add(PrimitiveLongHashSet.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxState.recordRelationshipDeleted(TxState.java:1353)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxState.relationshipDoDelete(TxState.java:550)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.RelationshipStateImpl.accept(RelationshipStateImpl.java:54)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxState.relationshipDoDeleteAddedInThisTx(TxState.java:578)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.relationshipDelete(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:472)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.relationshipDelete(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:310)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations.relationshipDelete(LockingStatementOperations.java:307)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.relationshipDelete(OperationsFacade.java:870)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.delete(RelationshipProxy.java:152)
    at com.abakus.cmm.dictionary.Neo4jDictionary.joinPersonNode(Neo4jDictionary.java:249)
    at com.abakus.cmm.dictionary.Neo4jDictionary.checkMergePersonNode(Neo4jDictionary.java:235)
    at com.abakus.cmm.dictionary.Neo4jDictionary.registerRecord(Neo4jDictionary.java:205)
    at com.abakus.cmm.dictionary.Neo4jDictionary.joinDictionary(Neo4jDictionary.java:331)
    at com.abakus.cmm.dictionary.Neo4jLongDictionary.mergeDictionary(Neo4jLongDictionary.java:82)
    at com.abakus.cmm.dictionary.Neo4jLongDictionary.mergeLongDictionary(Neo4jLongDictionary.java:52)
    at com.abakus.cmm.dictionary.Neo4jLongDictionary.main(Neo4jLongDictionary.java:103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Periodically committing transaction helped resolve above problem. However, TxState code can still be optimized and documentation added. This is there in Javadoc of this class

- This class is very large, as it has been used as a gathering point to consolidate all transaction state knowledge
- into one component. Now that that work is done, this class should be refactored to increase transparency in how it works.